# Error when running scala script from terminal; however :load works fine inside interpreter

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn Scala, or at least the basics for now.
I went to the scala website to download it from there. I followed the steps and download Coursier and called `cs setup` and then `cs install scala:3.1.1` and `cs install scalac:3.1.1`.

I started writing simple scripts without classes, like how you'd do in the interpreter. So I opened a text file and wrote `print('x')` and saved it to filename.scala, then I went to terminal and tried `scala filename.scala`; however, that gave me the error ("Illegal start of toplevel definition"). I changed the code inside the .scala file to a simple `var x : Int 4`, and I get a different error ("Error: No main methods detected in script Desktop/filename.scala").

When I open the scala terminal and use the :load option, everything works fine. After looking around SO for a good half an hour, none of the mentioned answers helped. I understand that scala is looking for a full program with objects and methods like java. But from what I read, it should be able to run scripts like the one I wrote by guessing its type. What's the problem? Is this a problem with scala 3 or my terminal? or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK is a bug on the **Scala 3** runner, it doesn't work with scripts. You may try looking at **Amonnite** or **Scala-cli** but really i would just create a small **sbt** project and start working there.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your answer. I've seen an answer recommending sbt too, but that's just a lot of unnecessary work for something simple. Ammonite is an ok option, since coursier downloads it by default. I'll probably use ammonite for now or rollback to scala 2, if the problem is in scala 3 as you said. Thanks again.